# Assigning an ID to each name specifically

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am trying to assign ID to each name, for ex. if the agentName is Bob, an ID is assigned to Bob, and when a new row of data is inserted, and the agentName is Bob, the ID will remain the same.

This is the sql table, any ways to code or use SQL to query it out?

```
  ----------------------------------------------
    ID  AgentName       Conversation             |
    ---------------------------------------------|          
    1   Bob             Hi                       |
    2   Mary            it should be 20-24 Jan   |
    3   Bob             oops                     |
    4   Jane            yeah feb                 |
    5   Jane            my typo                  |
    ----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Eclipse and mysql tag ? Maybe you forgot to add the language you use to program on this IDE ^^

Comment: Make an `integer` column with `autoincrement`, it will maintain what you want

Comment: @FoxCy yeah, sorry! I'm currently using java

Comment: @MayankPandeyz yes, that's what I did. The ID column is integer with autoincrement, but it didn't assign accordingly to each name

Answer (score 1):

in java you can create an HashMap (use the agent name as key and id as value). Then for each insert check if the agent name is present in HashMap; if you find a value use it else add a new element to the map. Don't forget to initialize the map

Following an example:

```
public class Prove {

  public static HashMap<String, Integer> agentsId = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  public static Integer counter = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      //Add new agent
      System.out.println("Bob " + addAgent("Bob"));
      System.out.println("Mary " + addAgent("Mary"));

      //Add old agent (return old id)
      System.out.println("Bob " + addAgent("Bob"));
  }

  public static int addAgent(String name) {
      if(agentsId.get(name)!=null) {
          //do your work
          return agentsId.get(name);
      } else {
          counter = counter + 1;
          agentsId.put(name, counter);
          //do your work
          return agentsId.get(name);
      }
  }

}
```